# Get something hot

Tags: adjectives, complements

If I say "I want to get my coffee hot", (In the literal sense),
does it mean I want to cause my coffee to be hot? or literally the same as "I want to receive my coffee hot"?

Comment: Why not “ I want to get my hot coffee” as for receiving?

Comment: @JayHo, your suggestion has a different emphasis. It says there is a cup of hot coffee that is yours in some sense, and you want to get it. The original says that when you get your coffee you want it to be hot.

Comment: @Peter thanks for ur explanation. Yes I eanted to emphasize the state of the coffee I am referring to  should be hot when I receive it

Comment: oh and any opion on whether it is possible to say "To get a coffee hot" as well??

Comment: Karl, you might say 'I want to get my coffee hot' if you had previously been served cold or lukewarm coffee, and you wished to passively-aggressively complain about that, in a way that belittles the barista (because you did not phrase it politely).

Comment: I see Didn't know about  the passive aggresiveness because when it is translated directly into Korean there is no such an implication. Thank you so much Michael!

Answer (score 3):

It can mean either of those things, depending on context.

Example 1:

> I'm holding a mug of coffee, take a sip, notice it's gotten cold, and say to my wife as I get
> up and head towards the microwave, "I want to get my coffee hot."

In the above example, "I want to get my coffee hot" means I want to cause it to be hot.

Example 2:

> I'm sitting at a diner where I've been served tepid coffee on multiple
> occasions in the past, which I loathe, so to try and prevent it from
> happening again, I say to the waiter taking my order, "I want to get
> my coffee hot."

In the above example, "I want to get my coffee hot" means I want to receive my coffee hot.

Comment: thank so much!!!

Comment: Is it also possible to say "Get a coffee hot"..??